# Finding Stalled or Failed Updates on System

Tags: rhel, upgrade, puppet

I was wondering if there is a way to grep through systems to find old updates that have stalled or failed. I am using RHEL 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you install a package or update.

If you are a `RedHat Satellite` customer there is a log in `/var/log/rhsm` called `rhsm.log` but it will still use a facility to install typically `yum`

`yum` There is a `yum.log` in `/var/log/`

`rpm` does not maintain logs, however you can run `rpm -qa --last` to see the list of packages that were installed and when but does not list failures.

The only way to see the failures would be at the command line.

You might be able to ascertain issues by looking at `history` but that is subjective and time consuming. You would have to search `history` and match up the installations or updates to installed packages. That also does not cover if something was installed or updated via other methods that were not run at a command line.

`Puppet` has a framework that it uses to perform `package` installations. It has a list of around 33 different providers for all OS's. It will search for the ability to install in a descending fashion typically defaulting to `yum` and falling back to `rpm`.

Because the typical syntax for `puppet` package installations is

```
    package { ssh;
    ensure => present
    }
```

The puppet framework determines after that based on your repository preferences and `costs` associated with installation media which to use then what to use to install it.

And you always have the typical fallback `/var/log/messages` you will sometimes see errors in there depending on what the failure was related to.

Also if the package was going to add a module or anything that `dmesg` would recognize and was backed out you might see info in `dmesg`

As far as unfinished, you would have to check `ps` for that. Or available `tty's` and `pty's`

Comment: Great thank you for the answer that definitely got the ball rolling for me. I'm sorry I can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputation..

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.